# How to add an If-Then conditional statement for a Google Form (Google Apps Script)?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, conditional-statements, google-forms

I have a simple Google form with two text entry fields and one checkbox.  If the user selects the checkbox, I want to run another function that will send an email message to the user; otherwise I want to skip the function.  I already have the script up and running, but my script is currently running the function to send an email for EVERY user - and I want to restrict the function from running only if the user selects the checkbox.

Comment: Please show the code/script you are using right now. So that way one can review your code and modify it as required. Also, if you can tell/show what you have tried so far it would be useful.

Comment: I copied the code from https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/google-forms-upload-workaround-connecting-drive-folder-amanda-blair and modified the variables for my Form name and column numbers, Spreadsheet and Google Drive.  There is a Trigger to execute the script when the Form is submitted.  It works fine - but I only want to execute the script IF the user selects "Yes" in the checkbox on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at CheckBoxItem class (on getChoices() method) [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#getChoices()) and the Choice class [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice)